# Deliver Inapp Purchases (Serverside)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

My app provides extra content in its inapp store (non-consumables). The products (external files) are all stored on my server, so I can dynamically add new. Once the user has bought an item, my server verifies it and remembers the transaction data.

How can I now deliver my content? Let's say the user buys it, exits the app, and comes back later to display the content. Since the data is on the server, my app now needs to query the server once again to get the content. How can the server verify that the client making the query is a valid buyer of the content? Should I save something (like the transaction ID) on the app and then verify through this? Or are there better approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to save the transaction ID and transaction date of a bought product on the local device. The server verifies through this. The ID and date are stored in the keychain, to give them some protection from being read by a 3rd party.

If someone has better suggestions, he/she can still post it.